# Menu in ie8 don't run

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a web menu that not runs in ie8, in ie7 runs well, i don't understand when is the problem.

This is the code html.

```
<div class="menu">
                <ul class="opcions"> 

                    <li class="menu_serveis"><a href="index.php?s=2&i=<? echo $i; ?>" title="serveis">serveis</a></li> 
                    <li class="menu_grafic"><a href="index.php?s=3&i=<? echo $i; ?>&p=0" title="grafic">grafic</a></li> 
                    <li class="menu_logos"><a href="index.php?s=4&i=<? echo $i; ?>" title="logos">logos</a></li> 
                    <li class="menu_senyalitzacio"><a href="index.php?s=5&i=<? echo $i; ?>" title="senyalitzacio">senyalitzacio</a></li> 
                    <li class="menu_planimetria"><a href="index.php?s=6&i=<? echo $i; ?>" title="planimetria">planimetria</a></li> 
                    <li class="menu_webs"><a href="index.php?s=7&i=<? echo $i; ?>" title="webs">webs</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_exposicions"><a href="index.php?s=8&i=<? echo $i; ?>" title="exposicions">exposicions</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_museografia"><a href="index.php?s=9&i=<? echo $i; ?>" title="museografia">museografia</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_packaging"><a href="index.php?s=10&i=<? echo $i; ?>" title="packaging">packaging</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_historic"><a href="index.php?s=11&i=<? echo $i; ?>" title="historic">historic</a></li>
                </ul> 
                </div>
```

This is the css code:

```
ul,li {
    list-style-type:none;
    }

.menu{
    height:350px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:-40px;
    }

.opcions li {
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    }

.opcions a {
    background:url('../../img/menu.png');
    display:block;
    width:380px;
    height:200px;
    text-indent:-9000%
    }


/*ESTADO NORMAL             -190px   */
.menu_serveis a {width:190px;height:20px; background-position:0px 0px;}
.menu_grafic a {width:190px;height:20px; background-position:0px -20px;}
.menu_logos a {width:190px;height:20px; background-position:0px -40px;}
.menu_senyalitzacio a {width:190px;height:20px; background-position:0px -60px;}
.menu_planimetria a {width:190px;height:20px; background-position:0px -80px;}
.menu_webs a {width:190px;height:20px; background-position:0px -100px;}
.menu_exposicions a {width:190px;height:20px; background-position:0px -120px;}
.menu_museografia a {width:190px;height:20px; background-position:0px -140px;}
.menu_packaging a {width:190px;height:20px; background-position:0px -160px;}
.menu_historic a {width:190px;height:20px; background-position:0px -180px;}

/*ESTADO ROLLOVER*/
.menu_serveis a:hover {background-position:-190px 0px;}
.menu_grafic a:hover {background-position:-190px -20px;}
.menu_logos a:hover {background-position:-190px -40px;}
.menu_senyalitzacio a:hover {background-position:-190px -60px;}
.menu_planimetria a:hover {background-position:-190px -80px;}
.menu_webs a:hover {background-position:-190px -100px;}
.menu_exposicions a:hover {background-position:-190px -120px;}
.menu_museografia a:hover {background-position:-190px -140px;}
.menu_packaging a:hover {background-position:-190px -160px;}
.menu_historic a:hover {background-position:-190px -180px;}

/*ESTADO ACTIVO*/
.menu_serveis a.active {background-position:-190px 0px;}
.menu_grafic a.active {background-position:-190px -20px;}
.menu_logos a.active {background-position:-190px -40px;}
.menu_senyalitzacio a.active {background-position:-190px -60px;}
.menu_planimetria a.active {background-position:-190px -80px;}
.menu_webs a.active {background-position:-190px -100px;}
.menu_exposicions a.active{background-position:-190px -120px;}
.menu_museografia a.active {background-position:-190px -140px;}
.menu_packaging a.active {background-position:-190px -160px;}
.menu_historic a.active {background-position:-190px -180px;}
```

The url of site is: http://abs.marcmorales.es/index.php?s=1&p=0&i=0

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `text-indent:-9000%` with `text-indent:-9000px` at `.options a` and it works also in IE8:
http://jsfiddle.net/tvhTD/1/

Comment: Yes, because the 25anys DIV is over the menu. Hide it, or implement it correctly (by setting a z-index, i.e.) and it will work ;-)

Comment: Thanks Armin, but i put menu with z-index:5; and 25anys z-index:0 and not runs...Thanks!

Comment: To make z-index work you need to add "position: relative;" to DIV.menu, of course.

Comment: Maybe you want to show your thankfulness, by flagging my answer as correct one ;-)

Comment: Do you use some application to see that div was over the menu? Thanks

Comment: The IE developer tools got a selector tool, which allows you to hover an element and get it selected in the source. I did it with the navigation but the 25anys DIV got selected ;-) Then the solution was easy.